# Fusing two git svn repos at point of divergence

Tags: git, svn, version-control

So, I'm trying to convert a couple of SVN repos to git-svn repos (in pursuit of cutting out SVN entirely in the long term, so we can shut off our SVN server).

Problem, though - the SVN branches have been merged and remerged and split enough times over the last 10 years that I can't just run `git svn fetch` and be done with it.

I've managed to get it so I now have two repos in two separate folders (we'll call them A and B), and I know where they diverged:

```
A ---------------*------- A
                  \
                   \
B                  -*------------------- B
```

(`A---A` is the git-svn commit history for directory A, `B---B` is the git-svn commit history for directory B, and `*` is the first commit on B/where B diverged from A.)

Is there a way to create a new repo (C) that effectively just contains the commit history of A up the the point of divergence, and then continues using B's path? (Below)

```
C ---------------*
                  \
                   \
                    *------------------- c
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Export the commits *-B as a series of patches and apply them to * in A.